# THREE.js Particles / PointCloud

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to get some orbiting objects to leave a trail. For this I have created a particle system which consists of a THREE Geometry, a THREE PointCloud, and a THREE PointCloudMaterial:

```
particleMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({ 
  color: 0xFFFFFF, size: 1, sizeAttenuation: false 
});
particles = new THREE.Geometry;
particles.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
particles.dynamic = true;
particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud( particles, particleMaterial );
scene.add( particleSystem );
```

To generate the vertices for the Geometry to form the trail, I am creating them in the animate loop and copying the position from the object they are to provide the trail for at that point in time:

```
function animate() {
if ( nodesArray.length > 0 ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < nodesArray.length; i++ ) {
        nodesArray[i].position.x = Math.sin( nodesArray[i].counterX ) * 50;
        nodesArray[i].position.z = Math.cos( nodesArray[i].counterZ ) * 50;
        nodesArray[i].position.y = Math.cos( nodesArray[i].counterY ) * 50;
        nodesArray[i].counterX += .01;
        nodesArray[i].counterZ += .01;
        nodesArray[i].counterY += .01;

        var particle = new THREE.Vector3();
        particle.copy( nodesArray[i].position );
        particles.vertices.push( particle );
        particles.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
}

requestAnimationFrame( animate );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jayfield1979/184kbyLr/

The first vertex for each object is added in the correct position. But subsequent vertices are not been registered.

Am I doing this correctly, if so what is broken? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Please read "Geometries". You can not add new vertices to geometry, that is why only your first vertex is visible.